# can't get ruby omniauth-ebay-oauth gem example code working

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth

I am trying to setup and use omniauth-ebay-oauth (https://github.com/evilmartians/omniauth-ebay-oauth) gem to use eBay rest APIs in my app without success.

I set up the required environment variables and run the example code but get a message saying "Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.". It does not recognise the '/auth/ebay' route, not sure if I have to declare that route myself nor what to put in it if I do. I'm new to ruby and Sinatra so do apologise if this is just something silly and obvious that I'm missing.

```
require 'omniauth-ebay-oauth'

use Rack::Session::Cookie
use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :ebay_oauth, ENV['EBAY_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['EBAY_CLIENT_SECRET'],
callback_url: ENV['EBAY_RU_NAME'], name: 'ebay'
end

get '/' do
redirect '/auth/ebay'
end

get '/auth/ebay/callback' do
"Hello, #{request.env['omniauth.auth'].dig('info', 'name')}"
end
```

I appreciate any help and insight in getting this working. I've googled everywhere and asking here as my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue on the GitHub repository and the gem creator replied in 3 hours. Totally life saver. I will post the solution here to help others.

> It is because of security settings of [OmniAuth 2.x](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/releases/tag/v2.0.0).
>
> Add the following line at the top, after requires:
>
> `OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods += %i[get]`

This worked like a charm and I can now move forwards with the project.